# file loss after change language

Tags: directory, language-support, data-loss

I loss my files in my Document, Music, Picture, Download folders after change the language in my User Account from English to my native language. How can I get my files back?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my files and the old folder (Downloads, Pictures, etc) are in home folder. I think if we change the language, the folder's the name will be automatically changed based on new language but they did not. I copy my file to be moved to my new folder.